# Issue adding a document library web part to sharepoint page

Tags: listview, sharepoint, web-parts, documents

I have code that programmatically creates a publishing web. It works fine except for one thing. I have to add the out of the box documents listview web part to the default.aspx page. It adds the web part, but it doesn't have the add document link at the bottom like you would see if you manually added the documents web part. What's strange is if I edit the web part, there are sections for List Views, Appearance, Layout and Advanced. I click OK without making changes and if I go back and edit the web part, there are 2 added sections. AJAX Options and Miscellaneous. If I click OK again without making changes, the add document link shows up.

```
string pageURL = "default.aspx";

SPFile destFile = newWeb.GetFile(pageURL);
if (destFile.Exists)
{
  if (destFile.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
    destFile.CheckOut();
}
else
{
    pageURL = "pages/default.aspx";
    destFile = newWeb.GetFile(pageURL);
    if (destFile.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
        destFile.CheckOut();
}

SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = 
    newWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageURL, PersonalizationScope.Shared);

// add the document library
SPList docLib;

if (!bHasDocuments)
{
    // create the document library
    Guid docLibGuid = newWeb.Lists.Add(
        "Documents", 
        "", 
        SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);

    docLib = newWeb.Lists[docLibGuid];
}
else
{
    docLib = newWeb.Lists["Documents"];
}

docLib.OnQuickLaunch = true;
docLib.Update();

SPDocumentLibrary spDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)docLib;
spDocLib.EnableVersioning = true;
spDocLib.EnableMinorVersions = false;

// add the doc lib to the home page
ListViewWebPart wpDoc = new ListViewWebPart();
wpDoc.ZoneID = "TopZone";
wpDoc.ListName = docLib.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
wpDoc.ViewGuid = docLib.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();

// Add the web part
mgr.AddWebPart(wpDoc, wpDoc.ZoneID, 20);
```

Any ideas how to get the web part to include the Add Document link?

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
 XsltListViewWebPart wpDoc = new XsltListViewWebPart();

INSTEAD OF ListViewWebPart wpDoc = new ListViewWebPart();

It worked for me in SP2013.